# How to join two arrays into fields of object

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-compass

In mongodb aggregate, I have below document:

```
{key:['a','b','c'], scores:[1,2,3]}
```

And want to change it to

```
{a:1, b:2, c:3}
```

How to do it in aggregate stage? I'm using MongoDB Compass Version 1.21.2 (1.21.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$zip`

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uCBYjJ7dKnb)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "output": {
        "$zip": {
          "inputs": [
            "$key",
            "$scores"
          ],
          
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

It maps the values the way you need but the format is different.

You can use `$unwind, $project, $arrayToObject` to convert further to the object structure.

As @turivishal pointed out, you can convert the above to the desired structure using (this)[mongoplayground.net/p/PSnIzI8nF0A].

Comment: nice, now its easy look at this https://mongoplayground.net/p/PSnIzI8nF0A

Comment: Very well, You completed the answer.

Comment: appreciate this solution, Thanks much.

I'm trying to do this: what if my field returns an object and not an array of objects like the one below. how would you aggreagate this:
```
{
    'key': [
      "a",
      "b",
      "c"
    ],
    'scores': [
      1,
      2,
      3
    ]
  }
```

The snippet you provided and aggregated is an array of object

Comment: No, it's an object. You confused by square brackets `[ ] `  around the data. That's the behaviour of `mongoplayground`.